# android: how i can make a list from database sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, user-interface

I want to make a list contains some username from my sqlite database. I want it has white background and black text. I felt difficult when find every tutorial thought me to use extends listactivity....is there any technique to make it ? 
here is some of my code in nir.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.changeplayer);
btnCreateN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateNew);
btnCreateN.setOnClickListener(this);
btnSetP = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
btnSetP.setOnClickListener(this);
//buat listview
lstUnameView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listUsername);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, 
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lstUname);
lstUnameView.setAdapter(adapter);


//koneksi ke db, ngambil username-username
helper = new sqlite(this, "tamadb", 1);
db1 = helper.getWritableDatabase();
c = db1.rawQuery("SELECT username FROM tama", null);
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
    lstUname.add(c.getString(0));
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
helper.close();
```

and this my code in layout changeplayer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listUsername" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="350px" 
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
                  android:background = "#FFFFFFFF" 
                  android:cacheColorHint = "#191919" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCreateNew" 
        android:layout_width="120px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Create New" 
        android:layout_below="@id/listUsername" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="40px" /> 
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="120px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="OK" 
        android:layout_below="@id/listUsername" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCreateNew" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help, i want to finish this project too...he9x..thx before...^^

Comment: is your question how to make the white background with black text (if so then see Flo's answer below) or do you want to know how to use ListActivity?

Comment: listactivity will ruin my code i think, because i have read it and getting confused about it, he9x....and after all, i dont know how write the other code in listactivity...he9x

Comment: i will find how to use theme first i think...he9x, thx before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your whole app to have white background and black text you can set the theme for your app to `Theme.Light`. Therefore you have to add the attribute `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"` to the  element of the manifest file.

Comment: hmmm...i just want that listview have white background and black text...he9x. Can you where i must put that attribute?

Comment: If only the list should be white with black background then you should define a custom layout xml for the list items. There you set the colors as you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout.xml I have put together for a listview with white background and black text.

You need to set the colours list_bg and menu_text to white and black respectively in your res folder then call the layout and id in your activity.

As far as populating a listview there is a good example here with downloadable code:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awu7Rlsez_k

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@color/list_bg">

<TextView android:background="@color/list_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/menu_text" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding ="10dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:id="@+id/row" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```